# Python + Selenium WebDriver, work with Pseudo-elements

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Please help. I need to activate the checkbox, but I don't understand how to refer to this pseudo-element **::before**.
Please, check this image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhwPZ.png)

The checkbox should look like this, so you can go to the next page
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uz8Ld.png)

The item is there, but I don't know how to activate the checkbox so that it changes color. I know I need to refer to the styles, but I don't know how to do that

```
checkbox = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'body > main > div > div > div > div.account-page > div.account-content.account-part > div > div.tab-content > div.race-event-general > div:nth-child(9) > div.checkbox > label > span')
checkbox.click()
time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: Can you share a link to that page?

Comment: Sorry, I can't because it's confidential, I can only share a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to access that pseudo element. Try clicking the `label` element there.
Also you have to improve your locators. Absolute locators are extremely breakable.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to click on this item? When I try to click, it's not the checkbox that gets selected, but the link next to it

Comment: To do so I need to see that page but you didn't share the link

Comment: Sorry, but I can only share a screenshot because I can't access this page

Comment: I understand. But we can't try nothing without minimal debugging details

Comment: Okay, I'll try to click on the label. Or if you have time and opportunity, we can use google meet so I can show you the screen

Comment: No, I'm sorry, I'm busy on my work.

Comment: When I try click on the label: selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable

Comment: You probably missing a delay or maybe need to scroll that element into the view. maybe something else. We need to debug that...

Comment: I think Selenium just can't click on this item because it is not a checkbox. It's a pseudo-element, maybe you need to work with styles?